# Touchpad speed changes when mouse is plugged in

Tags: kubuntu, touchpad, udev

Kubuntu 18.10

Each time I plug in my mouse(Razer Deathadder), my touchpad speed is set to a significantly decreased speed. I can temporarily fix it by going to the touchpad settings, where it displays the message,

> "Active settings don't match saved settings.
>   You currently see saved settings."

and simply pressing "Apply." How can I fix this, or make a script that reapplies the settings each time I plug in my mouse?

Edit: 
Using xinput, I discovered the property that is being changed. Initially, accel is set to:

```
libinput Accel Speed (292):     0.000000
```

After plugging in the mouse, it is set to:

```
libinput Accel Speed (292):     -0.780000
```

So, I can set the accel through terminal using:

```
xinput set-prop --type=float 18 "libinput Accel Speed" 0.000000
```

I looked up how to run a script when the mouse is plugged in. I made a udev rule, `/etc/udev/rules.d/100-reset-touchpad-accel.rules`:

```
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1532", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0037", OWNER="tuna", RUN+="/home/tuna/bin/reset_touchpad_accel.sh"
```

and made a script, `/home/tuna/bin/reset_touchpad_accel.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

xinput set-prop --type=float 18 "libinput Accel Speed" 0.000000
```

but it's not working.

Edit 2:
I've learned that I can use `tail -f /var/log/syslog` for debugging.
It seems I have to restart udev for changes to take effect `sudo service udev restart`

Looking at syslog, I saw a permissions issue that I fixed by prepending `/usr/bin/sudo -u tuna` to my udev rule.

```
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1532", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0037", RUN+="/usr/bin/sudo -u tuna /usr/local/bin/reset_touchpad_accel_udev.sh"
```

But, it still won't run. syslog says

```
Feb  1 19:11:00 tuna-Latitude-3350 systemd-udevd[21199]: Process '/usr/bin/sudo -u tuna /usr/local/bin/reset_touchpad_accel_udev.sh' failed with exit code 1.
```

Edit 3: I tried using `ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}+="/etc/systemd/system/reset-touchpad-accel.service"` instead of `RUN+=` and created a .service file

```
[Unit]
Type=oneshot

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/reset_touchpad_accel.sh
```

This isn't working either.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, would you try this solution https://askubuntu.com/q/1150247/26246